# Entity id is null after flush Jpa2

Tags: hibernate, jpa, flush

I'm using Hibernate and Jpa2 inside a spring based webapp.

When i try to save multiple entities i got an optimistic lock exception because the first saved entity Id is null even if the flush method is called.

In fact it should return insert entity along with its id as hibernate doc states.

the entity primary key is composed of two values like this:

```
    @Column(name = "tagId", nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    Integer tagId;

    @Column(name = "modelId", nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Id
    Integer modelId;
```

i think the problem is related to the fact that the tag id field is auto-generated and not "injected" as modelId.

the store dao method is listed below:

```
    @Transactional
        public Tag saveTag(Tag tag) {
            Tag existingTag = tagDAO.findTagByPrimaryKey(tag.getTagId(), tag.getModelId());

            if(existingTag != null){
                if(existingTag != tag){
                    existingTag.setTagId(tag.getTagId());
                    existingTag.setModelId(tag.getModelId());
                    existingTag.setVersion(tag.getVersion());
                    existingTag.setName(tag.getName());
                }
                tag = tagDAO.store(existingTag);
            }else{
                tag = tagDAO.store(tag);
            }
            tagDAO.flush();

            return tag;
          }
```

suggestions?

Comment: Can you try adding annotation like this to id field...
@GenericGenerator(name = "tagIdGenerator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "tagIdGenerator")

Comment: i try with this @GenericGenerator(name = "tagIdGenerator", strategy = "increment" ) @GeneratedValue(generator = "tagIdGenerator"), but doesn't work